# GTK Window Title Bar - Can't remove the Docker Container ID

Tags: docker, gtk, gtkmm

I have GTK (actually GTKMM) application running inside a Docker container.  The Docker container ID is always shown in the Title Bar of the Window, no matter what I do to try to change it, like calling set_title() ... it always adds "(on *docker id*)" to the title bar.  Just looking to see if anyone else has dealt with this issue, and if so, how they fixed it.  I understand how that docker id info might be useful, but I'd like to get rid of it if possible.[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that's the hostname(8) of the container...do you have the application code that creates the window frame?

Comment: Have you tried on another window manager?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I'd have to look at the GTK source for GTK.ApplicationWindow which creates the window frame.  I'll probably do that to see if figure this out.

Comment: @BobMorane - no, I haven't tried another window manager.  That would be a last resort sort of thing for me.

Comment: I was not suggesting it as a solution to your problem, but rather as a check this is indeed a GTK related issue instead of a window manager one.

Comment: @BobMorane -- doh!  You're exactly right.  Every app I launch, including commercial apps, have the  "(on .......)" with the container id in the title bar.  It appears to be a "feature" of the window manager.  It wasn't obvious to me since I typically don't run anything else in the container.